# Automating Creation of Network Dataset Using Polyline Input and ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, network-analyst, network-dataset

Is there a way to automate the creation of a Network Dataset in Model Builder using a line shapefile as an input? (ArcGIS 10.4)

The only documentation I have been able to find on creating a network dataset involves right clicking on a feature dataset > New > Network Dataset.

I have tried using the "Build Network" stand-alone tool, but it will not accept either a polyline or polylineM as an input. It seems like the "Build Network" tool simply re-builds any pre-existing network dataset.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to convert the polyline feature to line feature? I created my network dataset using line feature and it works.

Comment: Not sure what version this previous answer was for (not available in Model Builder)-- https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157759/creating-a-network-dataset-in-modelbuilder

Comment: Was this created within Model Builder? MoreMeowbell is specifically asking about Model Builder methods.

Comment: No. I simply created my network using "Build Network" stand-alone tool from ToolBox.

Comment: As the answer used to be no and still seems to be, can we ask it a different way... If we create the network dataset manually first, is it possible to then copy it in model builder, change the source data to updated datasets and then rebuild it within Model builder? so it retains all the settings for uturn, ferry etc but just builds based on the updated data. Both datasets would have the same structure and just have changes in the records.